# MarkLogic Query Console port showing 404 error

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have downloaded MarkLogic Server version 8.
I have configured initial admin steps and I am able to open http://localhost:8001 and http://localhost:8002. However while opening http://localhost:8000 shows 404 error.
This never happened before.
Can anyone please help me finding what might be the possible reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that port 8000 is used by some other application on your system.
You can either find and disable that application or change the port from 8000 to some other port (say 8100) from within the admin console.

Comment: yes, this was the case. I recently ran into same problem again and found the port is used by other application.

Answer (score 2):

Strange. Confirm the following:

- In MarkLogic, is the APP Server on port 8000 running? One scenario is that you have some other server on that port already. It is possible that the server is not started because it could not bind to that port.
- If the server IS running, then the issue could be with the rewriter:

  - It should be set to /MarkLogic/rest-api/8000-rewriter.xml
  - "rewriter resolves globally" should be set to "true"

Comment: Also check the error log to see if there's a port conflict on 8000. Since you've got access to the admin application, you should be able to go to http://localhost:8001/get-error-log.xqy?filename=ErrorLog.txt

Comment: It worked after I re-install MarkLogic server. Thanks anyways!!

Answer (score 0):

You should access http://{host}:8000/qconsole, thought you are missing something there in your url, it should be like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/qconsole
```

Comment: I have tried http://localhost:8000/qconsole as well as   http://localhost:8000/appservices but still not working. Problem is with 8000 port I guess

Comment: You could check in the admin page if the port is being used, check the HTTP servers, in the worst case remember qconsole is one app more, so you could find the code in the MarkLogic directory and create a new HTTP server with that code. It will works too.

Answer (score 0):

Review the following settings on the HTTP server setting, and under module location

1. Make sure you have the correct url rewriter - "MarkLogic/rest-api/8000-rewriter.xml"
2. Make sure to check True at "rewrite resolves globally"

[See App server HTTP setting here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOoeR.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the browser app as administrator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).